# How do I create database users for Cassandra on CosmosDB?

Tags: azure, cassandra, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-cassandra-api

I want to be able to create multiple users on my Cassandra app such that a user can only access specific databases. I've tried following the [official docs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_using/useSecureUsers.html) of DataStax to create users. However, cosmosdB doesn't let me add users or even LIST USERS as it gives a `No Host Available` error. I've tried altering the system_auth keyspace to change the replication strategy as mentioned in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58501331/error-when-trying-to-run-create-and-select-in-cqlsh-nohostavailable) but to no avail. Gives me `message="system_auth keyspace is not user-modifiable."`

How can I use the Database Users feature of Cassandra on CosmosDB?

What alternatives do I have to create logins such that a user is only able to access a specific keyspace

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems. I have cast a vote to have your post moved to dba.stackexchange.com instead. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

[Azure Cosmos DB for Apache Cassandra](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/cassandra/) (the product) is not a true Cassandra cluster. Instead, Cosmos DB [provides an API that is CQL compliant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/cassandra/introduction) so you can connect to Cosmos DB using Cassandra drivers.

There are limits to what Cosmos DB's API can provide and there are several [Cassandra features which are not supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/cassandra/support) which include (but not limited to) the following CQL commands:

- `CREATE ROLE`
- `CREATE USER`
- `LIST ROLES`
- `LIST USERS`

From what I understand, Cosmos DB uses [role-based access control (RBAC)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/role-based-access-control) and you'll need to provision access to your DB using the [Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/secure-access-to-data).

Cosmos DB also does not provide support for Cassandra permissions so you will not be able to grant granular permissions in the same way that you would in a traditional Cassandra cluster.

For more information, see [Apache Cassandra features supported by Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/cassandra/support). Cheers!